# Is there a way to refresh Google Analytics data in Big Query tables beyond the 72 hours?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have our Google Analytics 4 set up to export data into Big Query tables.
This is done in daily batches and then with intraday streaming. [Details here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en-GB&utm_id=ad).

The issue is, the daily batch tables are only updated for 72 hours after a first upload. This is a problem since some data on GA sessions, esp. when it comes to source and medium data, tends to get synced much later than 72 hours after the event. And so while I can see this data in the GA UI, it doesn't get pushed into Big Query.

Is there a way to "force" GA into refreshing the daily GA tables beyond the 72 hour threshold?

- I looked up the Google support pages to no avail.
- I investigated the GA export settings, nothing helpful there.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask